# Tkinter buttons commands don't run

Tags: python, button, tkinter, global-variables

I want to write a program where I need buttons to return an integer. So my idea was to create a local variable which gets changed.

The problem is, that the global variable value is somehow not defined.

Maybe somebody can help me? Thank you!!

```html
def nb_1():
    global value
    value=1

def nb_2():
    global value
    value=2

def valueNumber():
    global value
    
    b1=Button(frame_output, text='1', command=nb_1)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT)

    b2=Button(frame_output, text='2', command=nb_2)
    b2.pack(side=LEFT)

    x=value
    return x
    
print (valueNumber())
```

Comment: just define it somewhere on top of the program (outside of any function)

Comment: But then the value doesn't change :/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to define your global variable `value` outside of your functions. Also sice what `valueNumber()` do is just create buttons and **do not** call commands nb_1 and nb_2, but just assigns them as buttons commands. So returned value will be value you firstly assigned `value` to, here `0`.

If you want to print value every time you changed it by clicking buttons print value inside this functions like so

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk, LEFT

frame_output = Tk()

def nb_1():
    global value
    value=1
    print(value)

def nb_2():
    global value
    value=2
    print(value)

def valueNumber():
    global value

    b1=Button(frame_output, text='1', command=nb_1)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT)

    b2=Button(frame_output, text='2', command=nb_2)
    b2.pack(side=LEFT)

    x=value
    return x

value = 0
valueNumber()

frame_output.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried this, but I don't wanna print the value, I just wanna return it. The next step of the programm is a new function which needs a return value from the valueNumber function. If I do it like you said, the output is always 0 if I do print(valueNumber).

Comment: It is because you call it right after setting `value` to `0`, if you would call `valueNumber` after calling either `nb_1` or `nb_2`, returned value of `valueNumber` would be 1 or 2.

Comment: Ah okay! And is there any possibility to get a return value when I hit the button?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but since `value` is global variable you can access it without needing to return it from any function.

Comment: okay, I'm sorry, I'll try to explain. Actually in my valueNumer function I have a lot of if conditions. I've just written one of them. So every condition returns another value, so it would bei nice, if this condition could return a value, depending on which button was hitted, because otherwise I have to change everything. 
Or is it maybe possible to just set a variable by hitting the button without using a function?

Comment: *this condition could return a value, depending on which button was hitted*, basically only purpose of using buttons is to execute some function when hitting it, code i provided does what you expect `valueNumber` is returning `value` which is equal to number corresponding to one of functions that were executed by pressing buttons.